# CPU overload: need to remove the (sed -n)

Tags: bash, sed

CPU overload. I need to find a way to run the script without the (sed -n) it uses to much CPU power if I run it.

```
#!/bin/bash
 # this script should read the log that i enter and find the last five min
 # give me a count and if i need to i can enter up to 5 different key
 # words to search for.
loyg=$1
loug=$(echo "$1" | sed -e 's/\//\n/g'  | tail -n1)
var0=$2
var=$3
var1=$4
var2=$5
dates=$(date +%s)
date=$(date +"%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")
datepoint=$(date +"%d.%m.%Y %H:%M" -d "5 mins ago")
    sleep 2
if [ -f $loug ];then
      intex=$(sed -n "/$date/,/$datepoint/p" "$loyg")
      count=$(echo  "$intex" | wc -l)
      error=`echo "$intex" | grep "$var0"`
      anyn=`echo "$intex" | grep "$var"`
      fails=$(echo  "$error" | wc -l)
      rand=$(echo  "$anyn" | wc -l)
      anyn1=`echo "$intex" | grep "$var1"`
      rand1=$(echo  "$anyn1" | wc -l)
      anyn2=`echo "$intex" | grep "$var2"`
      rand2=$(echo  "$anyn2" | wc -l)
fi
if   [ "$var0" != "" ] ;then
    echo "$dates: $count" "$fails" "$rand" "$rand1" "$rand2"    

    >> "stat_$loug-"$(date +"%Y%m%d")
    elif [ "$var" != "" ] ;then
    echo "$dates: $count" "$fails" "$rand" "$rand1" "$rand2" 
    >> "stat_$loug-"$(date +"%Y%m%d")
    elif [ "$var1" != "" ] ;then
    echo "$dates: $count" "$fails" "$rand" "$rand1" "$rand2"    
    >> "stat_$loug-"$(date +"%Y%m%d")
    elif [ "$var2" != "" ] ;then
    echo "$dates: $count" "$fails" "$rand" "$rand1" "$rand2"   
    >> "stat_$loug-"$(date +"%Y%m%d")
    else
    echo "$dates: $count" "0" "0" "0" "0" >> "stat_$loug-"$(date +"%Y%m%d")
fi
    scp "stat_$loug-"$(date +"%Y%m%d") datacopy2@vimapmop-    
    sta01.it.bwns.ch:/var/log/statistic/sis/"stat_$loug-"$(date +"%Y%m%d")  
    echo done
```

I need to replace the line with sed -n in it, it uses to much CPU power

I have tried running it with a "awk" but it didn't work out maybe I ran it wrong but it don't think so this is what I did :

```
intex=$(awk '{ print "/$date/,/$datepoint/p"}' "$loyg")
```

Comment: Like this : `awk '/$date/,/$datepoint/{print} "$loyg"`

Answer (score 0):

I seriously doubt that the main problem is the sed command in itself.
To test this theory just time it:

```
$ loyg="some_reasonable_value"
$ date=$(date +"%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")
$ datepoint=$(date +"%d.%m.%Y %H:%M" -d "5 mins ago")
$ time { sed -n "/$date/,/$datepoint/p" "$loyg"; } > /dev/null
```

The biggest problem with your script is that it suffer of `pipe-itis`.
For example, the assignment for `$loug`:

```
loug=$(echo "$1" | sed -e 's/\//\n/g'  | tail -n1)
```

echo the value of "$1" to `sed` (an external utility) to change every `/` into a `new line` to then pipe it to `tail` (also an external utility) to select the last line.
What that whole pipe does is to select the last value after an `/`.
That could simply be done with this:

```
loug=${1##*/}
```

That is remove everything in the front of the value of variable `$1` until the last `/`. No external utility called, faster, simpler.

It could be argued that it is not such a big issue because it is called only one time for the whole script adding very little additional time of execution.

True, but repeating such constructs for the whole content of a large file will take a long time. Each line will add some delay till it becomes very slow.

In fact, what is done on the first line inside the first if block is:

```
intex=$(sed -n "/$date/,/$datepoint/p" "$loyg")
```

That will copy a list of lines to the variable `$intex`.
And then, that list of lines is repeatedly filtered and copied to other variables:

```
error=`echo "$intex" | grep "$var0"`
```

All to finally just count the number of lines:

```
fails=$(echo  "$error" | wc -l)
```

Those two lines could be done by making grep to print the count.
Both lines will be reduced to:

```
fails=`echo "$intex" | grep -c "$var0"`
```

That will avoid the use of memory to store `$error` and the looong time it takes to a shell script to process large amounts of lines.

But: Could we do better?

Of course!!:
as soon as we realize that all that is needed from that part of the script is five counts (five numbers):

```
$count $fails $rand $rand1 $rand2
```

We could build an AWK script (a better tool to process large files than a shell script) to generate the five counts:

```
    getcounts(){
        awk -v dp="$datepoint" -v d1="$date" -v v0="$var0" -v va="$var" -v v1="$var1" -v v2="$var2" '
            ($0~dp),($0~d1){
                                                  count++;
                             if (v0!="" && $0~v0) fails++;
                             if (va!="" && $0~va) rand0++ ;
                             if (v1!="" && $0~v1) rand1++;
                             if (v2!="" && $0~v2) rand2++;
                           }
                       END { 
                             printf( "%d %d %d %d %d",count,fails,rand0,rand1,rand2 );
                           }
        ' "$loyg"
    }
```

The awk script only keeps five number in memory (a very low consumption of memory) and is a lot faster to process all the lines in the log than shell.

Some additional issues of your script:

1. The whole second if statement with all the tests and the `>>` to a file,
   could be reduced to this four lines:

   ```
   outlog="stat_$loug-"$(date +"%Y%m%d")
   result="$dates: $count $fails $rand $rand1 $rand2"
   [[ $var0 || $var || $var1 || $var2 ]] || result="$dates: $count 0 0 0 0"
   echo "$result" >> "$outlog"
   ```

   which, if the test for each var0/var...etc is done in the awk script, could be completely removed.
2. The order of /$date/,/$datepoint/ seems wrong to me. `$datepoint` is first in time and therefore should be before `$date`.

   The awk script has included this change.

#### Final script

```
#!/bin/bash

read loyg var0 var var1 var2 <<<"$@"

loug=${loyg##*/}

outlog="stat_$loug-"$(date +"%Y%m%d")

datepoint=$(date +"%d.%m.%Y %H:%M" -d "5 mins ago")    
dates=$(date +%s)
date=$(date +"%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")

    getcounts(){
        awk -v dp="$datepoint" -v d1="$date" -v v0="$var0" -v va="$var" -v v1="$var1" -v v2="$var2" '
            ($0~dp),($0~d1){
                                                  count++;
                             if (v0!="" && $0~v0) fails++;
                             if (va!="" && $0~va) rand0++;
                             if (v1!="" && $0~v1) rand1++;
                             if (v2!="" && $0~v2) rand2++;
                           }
                       END { 
                             printf( "%d %d %d %d %d",count,fails,rand0,rand1,rand2 );
                           }
        ' "$loyg"
    }


if [ -f "$loug" ]; then
        result="$( getcounts )"
else
        result="0 0 0 0 0"
fi

echo "$dates: $result" >> "$outlog"

destfile="datacopy2@vimapmop-sta01.it.bwns.ch:/var/log/statistic/sis/$outlog"

scp "$outlog" "$destfile"
echo done
```